# BeautifulSoup unable to get Inner tags

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape product data off lazada.sg using bs4 in the below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.lazada.sg/shop-mobiles/"
page = requests.get(url)
content = page.text #read html
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "c16H9d"}) #find div tags containing product details
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(products))
```

However the output in `test.txt` is just `[]`. 
I found that the above class is in `<div id="root">`, which I extracted and got [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6USE.png).

How will I be able to access the 'inner div tags'?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO43j.png) is a snippet of the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is dynamically loaded from script tag. You can regex out and use json library to view. You will need to adjust print line presumably for 2.7

```
import requests, re, json, pprint

r = requests.get('https://www.lazada.sg/shop-mobiles/')
p = re.compile(r'window.pageData=(.*)<')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])

for item in data['mods']['listItems']:
    pprint.pprint(item)
    break # delete me later
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am unable to write the contents to a `.txt` file though, with the output being `NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone`